# Call an F# ticked function name with embedded spaces (``XXX YY``) from C#

Tags: c#, f#, c#-to-f#

In F#, we can create a function like this:

```
let ``add x and y`` x y = x + y
```

And I can call it normally like this:

```
``add x and y`` 1 2
```

Is there a way to call the function above from C# side? I couldn't even see it in Object Browser though.

Comment: Reflection? That might be the only way.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about that, but it will make code harder to read. I think I could just re-bind the function with C#-friendly name instead.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can expose any [valid](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597387) F# function name to C# as any C# valid function name using [CompiledName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340493.aspx) attribute:

```
namespace Library1
module Test = 
    [<CompiledName("Whatever")>]
    let ``add a and b`` x y = x + y
```

and then in C#:

```
 using Library1;
 ...............
 System.Console.WriteLine(Test.Whatever(2,2));
```

**FOLLOW-UP 03/05/2016** on comment from [NickL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/853678/nickl), applies at least to F#3.1:

Moving from functions to members brings some "ifs and buts".

To begin with, `CompiledName` attribute does not compile with `member` if being used from pure `namespace`. The mere compilation requires use within a `module`.

When being used within a `module` and decorating *method* `member` of F# record it works just fine regardless of how the contents between two ticks looks. However when decorating *property* `member` of F# record `CompiledName` is visible cross-assembly only if contents between double ticks resembles *some* legal value name:

```
module M

type MyRecord =
    { myField: string }
    [<CompiledName "Whatever">]
    member x.``Blah Blah blah``() = x.myField
    [<CompiledName "Another">]
    member x.``ABC`` = x.myField
```

and then from C# the following works OK:

```
var recInC = new M.MyRecord("Testing...");
Console.WriteLine(recInC.Whatever());
Console.WriteLine(recInC.Another);
```

Such inconsistencies prompt for potential [issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/977).

Comment: Ah, I knew there was some attribute out there that did this.

Comment: @NickL: Please see the follow-up to the original answer.

Answer (score 6):

Reflection might be the only way, but it doesn't have to be ugly to use.  Just wrap it all within a class to do the reflecting.

```
public static class MyModuleWrapper
{
    // it would be easier to create a delegate once and reuse it
    private static Lazy<Func<int, int, int>> addXAndY = new Lazy<Func<int, int, int>>(() =>
        (Func<int, int, int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int, int, int>), typeof(MyModule).GetMethod("add x and y"))
    );
    public static int AddXAndY(int x, int y)
    {
        return addXAndY.Value(x, y);
    }

    // pass other methods through.
    public static int OtherMethod(int x, int y)
    {
        return MyModule.OtherMethod(x, y);
    }
}
```

Then use it like normal.

```
var sum = MyModuleWrapper.AddXAndY(1, 2);
var otherValue = MyModuleWrapper.OtherMethod(1, 2); // use the wrapper instead
```

I'm not sure what needs to be changed or how if there are polymorphic types involved, but hopefully you get the idea and can apply the necessary changes.